# A sentence, 'A but B is C.'

Tags: sentence-construction

You know, not A but B is C, not only A but also B is C, or A is B but C structures are correct. What about an A but B is C structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"not A but B is C"  This works, A and B are nouns and C is a complement that may be a noun or adjective.  It is slightly stilted;  "B, but not A, is C" would often be better.

> Not cats, but dogs are friendly

"not only A but also B is C" This also works and is slightly more emphatic than the equivalent "both A and B are C"

> Not only cats, but also dogs are friendly

"A is B but C"  I can't make this structure work for nouns A,B and C.  It would be possible for C to be a new clause. So we can't say "Dogs are friendly, but cats*" We can say "Dogs are friendly, but cats aren't"

"A but B is C" I can't make this work either with nouns.  You can't say "Dogs but cats are friendly*"  You might say Dogs are, but cats aren't friendly"  (but you don't want to do this too often, because one needs to back-track to understand the sentence)